# Raspberry pi python serial interface

Tags: python, serial-port

Let me reformulate the problem, sorry...

Need to monitor serial port and reply back.
while I am monitoring serial port I have other tasks to do, like, monitor IO, WEb server, etc.

I manage to have it running, monitoring the serial port but looses a lot of messages received...

Code used to test (simulating other equipment sending messages to the serial port. this bit of code sends a message to the Raspberry serial port every second.

```
import time
from serial_config import serial_port2

counter=0
aux = 0

while 1:
        #str = "Write counter: %d \n"%(counter)
        
        while aux < 10:
                straux = "{AAF0T000L0I0M0?00000" + str(aux) + "}f"
                #straux = "{" + str(aux) + "}f"
                serial_port2.write(straux.encode())
                print(straux)
                time.sleep(1)
                counter += 1
                aux = aux + 1
        aux = 0
```

On my raspberry pi I am listening and this is the code that I have.

```
...
#### monitores serial port ###########################################

serial_port1 = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1
)

def Monitoring_SerialPort_thr():
    global serial_message_received
    while(True):
       serial_port1.nonblocking()
        
        serial_message_received = serial_port1.read(100)
        serial_message_received = 
        message_validation(serial_message_received)
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Init()
    #lock_configfile = threading.Lock()
    
    Flashing_LED_thread = threading.Thread(target = Flashing_LED_thr)
    Running_Time_thread = threading.Thread(target = Running_Time_thr)
    Monitoring_SerialPort_thread = threading.Thread(target = Monitoring_SerialPort_thr)
    Monitoring_ADC_thread = threading.Thread(target = Monitoring_ADC_thr)
    Monitoring_IO_thread = threading.Thread(target = Monitoring_IO_thr)
    Save_Config_File_thread = threading.Thread(target = Save_Config_File_thr)
    Save_Config_STATUS_thread = threading.Thread(target = Save_Config_STATUS_thr)
    Web_Server_thread = threading.Thread(target = Web_Server_thr)

    Flashing_LED_thread.start()
    Running_Time_thread.start()
    Monitoring_SerialPort_thread.start()
    Monitoring_ADC_thread.start()
    Monitoring_IO_thread.start()
    Save_Config_File_thread.start()
    Save_Config_STATUS_thread.start()
    Web_Server_thread.start()
          
    Flashing_LED_thread.join()
    Monitoring_SerialPort_thread.join()
    Monitoring_ADC_thread.join()
    Monitoring_IO_thread.join()
    Running_Time_thread.join()
    Save_Config_File_thread.join()
    Save_Config_STATUS_thread.join()
    Web_Server_thread.join()
```

the problem I am having is that the serial port reading is missing messages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your Python code is not reading a "*serial port*"; **/dev/ttyUSB0** refers to a serial terminal attached through USB. See [Linux serial drivers](https://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html)
 for how removed your code is from the HW, and the buffering involved. There's no need for using non-blocking mode. Linux can provide event-driven scheduling that is far more efficient than user-based polling.

Comment: sorry... my mistake, using serial port instead the USB adaptor, port='/dev/serial0'